# Change Access database code to T-SQL code

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I need to change MS Access database code to T-SQL code.

Here is the SQL in MS Access:

```
SELECT Max("SPR-" & Val(Replace([RequestID],"SPR-",""))+1) AS AutoID 
FROM Tb_Request
```

Do you have any idea how to change this?

Any comments would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

**If 2012+**

```
Select AutoID = format(max(1+replace(RequestID,'SPR-','')),'SPR-#')
 From @YourTable
```

**If Pre-2012**

```
Select AutoID = 'SPR-'+cast(max(1+replace(RequestID,'SPR-','')) as varchar(25))
 From @YourTable
```